# Is it possible to translate special marks for Q_PROPERTY?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a bit properties.

```
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ readProp WRITE setProp NOTIFY propChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString description READ readProp WRITE setProp NOTIFY propChanged)
    ...
    Q_PROPERTY(QString date READ readProp WRITE setProp NOTIFY propChanged)

QString Company::readProp()
{
    QString name = [name | description | date] ??? //How to unificate my getter for traslation prop's names???
    return getAttr(name).toString();
}

QString Company::readProp()
{
    QString name = Q_TRASLATION_PROP_NAME
    return getAttr(name).toString();
}
```

May be has another way do it with QMetaObject info?
And i want avoid ti use the QQmlPropertyMap, because it working incorrectly!
I want to get name of property inside of getter

Comment: I'm pretty sure, at least with Qt 5, that each *compile-time* property needs its own unique get and set function.  However, you can simply just initialize a group of properties at *run time* using `setProperty` and similar. Not sure how you declare a signal for such properties to indicate change notifications.

Comment: It's a shame that i can't reuse my getter. And it's very strange there is no parameters for getter inside or other info.

Comment: I'm certain you could easily define your own macro that would accomplish what you want....

Comment: If you want a getter that takes parameters, why not just make a Q_INVOKABLE function?

Comment: Can you describe the real problem? Do you simply want stored properties to be a little less verbose?

Comment: You need to create individual getters, which call the unified getter with an extra parameter. Not a lot of code if you need this. But why?

Comment: Luca Carlon
Oposite, i just want to reuse my getter myltiple times for various prop names. And of cours for other aims...